# Does Apple Watch Cellular clone the SIM card?

Tags: sim, apple-watch

I have read, that Apple Watch will have the same phone number as iPhone and if iPhone is far away, it can connect to cellular network itself.

Doesn't this mean that Apple Watch clones the SIM and how this corresponds with the statement, that modern GSM network SIMs can't be cloned?

Answer (score 4):

I just checked the SIM ID on my iPhone and paired AppleWatch, and they are different.

I'm not sure why you are assuming that sharing a phone number implies cloning a SIM card. Carriers can design their networks to handle multiple SIM IDs associated with the same account. It's basically the same as two license plates being registered to the same person.

Comment: The phone number, to the network, isn't even shared. The Watch has a separate phone number. Calls from the original numbers are forwarded via the same FaceTime mechanisms that allow a computer to receive calls.

Comment: I don't assume, I am suggesting and asking what is true...

Answer (score 2):

It's an e-SIM, not a physical card you insert.

It's already known to your carrier & is activated & downloaded to your Watch as part of the setup process.

From [Apple KB - Set up and use cellular on Apple Watch Series 3 (GPS + Cellular)](https://support.apple.com/HT207578)

> Set up your cellular plan
>
> You can activate Apple Watch Series 3 (GPS + Cellular) when you first
>   set up your Apple Watch. During setup, look for the option to set up
>   cellular, then follow the onscreen steps.   Or you can set up cellular
>   later:
>
> - On your iPhone, open the Apple Watch app.
> - Tap the My Watch tab, then tap Cellular.
> - Tap Set Up Cellular. Follow the instructions for your carrier. You might need to contact your carrier for help.

And from EE [UK supplier] - [How do I set up my Apple Watch Series 3 (GPS + 4G)?](http://ee.co.uk/help/add-ons-benefits-and-plans/calling-texting-and-data-add-ons/apple-watch-series-3-ee-set-up-and-plans)

> Do I need to insert the eSIM?
>
> No, your Apple Watch Series 3 (GPS + 4G) includes an eSIM. It's not a
>   physical SIM and is instead automatically downloaded and activated as
>   part of the set-up process, so don't worry -  it's all ready to go.

Comment: I know it is e-SIM. My question is: if Apple Watch can clone my SIM, why other people like hackers and other entites can't?

Comment: "carrier" means "provider"? does this mean Apple Watch is tied to specific provider?

Comment: In the UK there's only one provider/carrier who offers it, so no-one here can tell yet if they're carrier-locked. & the watch is not cloning your sim in any way shape or form, your carrier is sending you an 'e-cert'. Presumably, they thought about potential hacking before deciding on the format, you'd guess it's not a plain text file ;)